# About parallel time computation

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I am studying a paper where it is mentioned that Newton iteration may be used to compute the inverse of $n \times n$, well- conditioned matrix in parallel time $o(\log^2n)$ and that this computation is processor efficient. I want to understand meaning of this term. What is parallel time computation and how can this be useful for any iteration method?

[Here is the link](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0912058)

Thank you very much.

Comment: A link to the paper would be appreciated.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Ok let me edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is meant here is more in the realm of computer science than pure mathematics, so if you don't have a strong computer background it may help to read the [Wiki entry on Parallel Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing). Basically, a [parallel algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_algorithm) is used to let multiple processor cores act at the same time rather than a single core acting alone. The efficiency of a parallel algorithm is based on a measurement of *parallel time*, which is defined as the time it takes for the parallel algorithm to run. To be considered efficient, the algorithm must satisfy: $$T_{sequential} \approx T_{parallel} * N_{cores}$$
Where $T_{sequential}$ is the run time of best known serial algorithm.

The efficiency of the parallel algorithm you referenced is then given in terms of poly-logarithmic time: $O (\log^c(n))$ where *c* is a constant and *n* is the size of the data set. See the Wiki article on [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Polylogarithmic_time) for a more detailed explanation of poly-logarithmic (and other) time scales.

It is also interesting to note that iterative algorithms such as Newton's method are usually considered *inherently serial*, i.e. quite difficult to (efficiently) parallelize.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How o determine the constant $c$?  I need little more detail. I haven't computer science background so it is little hard for me to understand.

Comment: @mathscrazy : It is common practice in computer science to notate efficiency function by prefixing them with an *O*. As far as I am aware the *O* has no other meaning. The constant *c* is dependent on the particular algorithm, and is found by comparing the *serial time* and *parallel time*. A lower value of *c* denotes a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: 2307487 Can we say anything about the minimum value of $c$? I mean is it possible to make $c$ less than one. Thanks for the answer. It helped me to in many ways.

Comment: @mathscrazy : Well if c=1, then it would be logarithmic time instead of poly-logarithmic time, as for 0<c<1, it *may* be possible, but I can't say for sure. These wiki articles may help you get a better understanding: [O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Use_in_computer_science), [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Polylogarithmic_time), [analysis of algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms).

Comment: 230 Thanks for the help. :)